# Using Codeigniter active record for "within distance" query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, dictionary

I'm trying to create the following query in CI using ActiveRecord

```
SELECT *, 
   ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) 
   * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
   * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) 
   + sin( radians($lat) ) 
   * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM locations 
HAVING distance <= $miles 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

I tried

```
$where = "( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM locations";        
$this->db->where($where);                           
$this->db->having('distance <= ' . $miles);                     
$this->db->order_by('distance');                    
$this->db->limit(20, 0);
```

The problem (I think) is that I'm already telling from which table I'm getting data via `$query = $this->db->get('locations');` at the end of my model. So I'm getting the following error:

> A Database Error Occurred Error
>   Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'AS distance
>   FROM user_profiles HAVING `distance`
>   <= 100 ORDER BY `distance` LIMI' at
>   line 5
>
> SELECT * FROM (`locations`) WHERE
>   `country` = 'US' AND `tags` = 'technology' AND 
>   `( 3959 * acos( cos(
>   radians(25.9331488) ) * cos( radians(
>   lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) -
>   radians(-80.1625463) ) + sin(
>   radians(25.9331488) ) * sin( radians(
>   lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM
>   locations HAVING`distance`<= 100
>   ORDER BY`distance` LIMIT 20
>
> Filename:
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Some things to note.. I'm using a few `where()` functions in my model. The distance query should coexist with other clauses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the `distance` calculation as a `WHERE` in your SQL.  You want it in your `SELECT`.  Didn't test, but try:

```
$this->db->select("*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance");                         
$this->db->having('distance <= ' . $miles);                     
$this->db->order_by('distance');                    
$this->db->limit(20, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

$miles= 20;
        $this->db->select("*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($shop_lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($shop_long) ) + sin( radians($shop_lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance");
        $this->db->from('shop');
        $this->db->having('distance <= ' . $miles);
        $this->db->order_by('distance');
        $this->db->limit(20, 0);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
}

Comment: Clarify your answer, but also keep in mind this was closed down 5 years ago.